# Cover breaking nav TOC in InDesign EPUB export

Tags: epub, adobe-indesign

I've exported a file to EPUB using CS5.5  but my options for nav TOC and breaking up the document aren't being honored. I used the Articles panel, created and applied a nav TOC style and selected the paragraph style  where the document should break but it results in just one html file being created. I'm using Adobe Digital Editions and Calibre to preview.

I dumped my InDesign preferences and re-created the file but the problem persists.

Further research has shown it's the cover file causing the problem. I've turned all text to outlines and sized it to 600x800px. File size is 212K. There are no ampersands in the file name. File name is written as "ABCCover.jpg." Tried other cover jpgs and it exports properly.

I've researched this on Adobe forum, stackoverflow and Google but no answers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem.  I am running Indesign CS5.5 on OSX 10.7.5.

I can have a working exported epub with the cover option of rasterizing the first page option set.  But if I change to an external graphic file (option 3) for the cover, then I lose the TOC as well as all my page breaks that are set for my chapter title paragraph style setting.

I am pasting a response that I got on another forum:

OK, it's definitely not your file or anything you're doing.

It's a limitation in InDesign CS5.5. It's not doing what it's supposed to be doing. It's not really writing the XHTML and the CSS so that your independent cover image can be used.

I was using InDesign CS5.5 when I was learning to create EPUB. I largely used writings by Elizabeth Castro and videos by Anne-Marie Concepcion. In Elizabeth's excellent first EPUB about creating EPUB, she describes how you created a cover (in CS5 days) by creating an XHTML file for the cover, and writing the code (she showed you how), and how you had to make a few changes in the other files I'll describe before.

When I first started creating EPUBs CS5.5 had the Rasterize First Page method. I never tried the independent cover file method. Anne-Marie doesn't even show it in her InDesign CS5.5 to EPUB video.

I was only when I started using CS6, that I tried the independent method and it worked. I never tried it in CS5.5. Not everything is written correctly.

So if you want to continue to use CS5.5, you'll need to create is by modifying code. I'd suggest picking up Elizabeth Castro's EPUB. Here's the link:

Formatting ebooks - EPUB Straight to the Point - Elizabeth Castro

You'll find directions in the Inside an EPUB file > Creating the cover.

You'll need to use an EPUB editor to add the "CoverImage.xhtml" file to the OEBPS folder.

Then you'll need to add your JPEG file to the "image" folder in the OEBPS (or make an image folder)

Then you'll need to edit three parts of the "content.opf" file: To the metadata, to the manifest, and to the spine.

//////////////////

I am now trying to verify that CS6 actually works properly.